# Error when i want insert a date in DB with laravel

Tags: postgresql, date, eloquent, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I'm using laravel 5.1 with eloquent, i have a postgre database and i would like to insert an object with some date in. My start format date is like '15/10/2015', and i need to convert into 'Y-m-d'.

For that i use date mutators in my model, i add this line :

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'prj_start_date', 'prj_end_date_init'];
```

I use an architecture with services and repositories so in my repository for create my object in DB i have this :

```
$this->model->create($data);
```

When i try to insert i have this error

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: 
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing
in Carbon.php line 425
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '15/10/2015') in Model.php line 2959
at Model->asDateTime('15/10/2015') in Model.php line 2915
at Model->fromDateTime('15/10/2015') in Model.php line 2870
at Model->setAttribute('prj_start_date', '15/10/2015') in Model.php line 422
```

Why isn't work, i've miss something ?
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

In `at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '15/10/2015') in Model.php line 2959` it is pretty clear that somehow laravel *hardcoded* it's dates mutator. I suggest using a manual approach, converting your string into `Carbon` instance via:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);
```

for example assuming have a date field instead of timestamp:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '15/10/2015');
```

**ps**. i did not have the time to test this yet. Nevertheless, learning from the [source](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) is much interesting right?

**ps**. you might interested in changing laravel's format just like [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) however, i suspect this will affect `created_at` and `updated_at` (also `deleted_at`) fields that by default is a timestamp instead of dates.

**ps**. right, i do forget to mention you had to include **Carbon** to your controller, just add `use Carbon/Carbon`

Comment: Thanks but i want convert my date in controller (i have a lot of date). I solve my problem. I add a mutator for all my date.`code : private function setPrjStartDateValue($value) {
        $date_parts = explode('/', $value);
        $this->attributes['prj_start_date'] = $date_parts[2].'-'.$date_parts[0].'-'.$date_parts[1];
    }`

Comment: well, that's one of the solutions (but not the one i think of). glad you sort it out.